# How to split a sentence into separate words followed by a comma using PHP

Tags: php, split

Hello guys I've been searching the net for this subject but I did not find a explicit answer... so I thought about asking you.

Here is the idea:

Lets say I have a string Example: This is a long string.

I want to separate that string into individual words followed by a comma.

Example: This,is,a,long,string

How do I do that in PHP

Comment: Maybe you could tell us what language you use

Comment: Is there a particular language? In this example, you could just find & replace each space with a comma.

Comment: I throw an idea for SO: no language tag = CANNOT post the question, no more waste of time :-) maybe adding the language "neutral" for pure algorithmics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use php methods:

```
// $str <- "This is a long string";
$comma_str = implode(',', explode(' ',$str));
```

or

```
$comma_str = str_replace(' ', ',', $str);
```

Or use a regexp.

Comment: I'm glad it helped! :D take a look at this references : http://php.net/docs.php, you may find a lot of alternatives for what you try to achieve

Answer (score 0):

```
[^,]+
```

If you are familiar with regex, this might give you every comma-separated words.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand

did you tried replace all space by comma?

```
var foo = "This is a long string";
var bar = foo.Replace(" ", ",");
```